# How to write test case readFile method which return type is void

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am new in writing test cases, Please help me for writing test case for below methods . Thanks in advance!!

```
public void readFile() throws IOException{
  linesProcessed = 0;
  FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
  DataInputStream dataInStream = new DataInputStream(fileInStream);
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInStream));
  String strLine;

  fileData.clear();
  while(StringUtils.isNotBlank((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()))) {
    ++linesProcessed;
    processLine(strLine);
  }
  bufferedReader.close();
  dataInStream.close();
  fileInStream.close();         
}
```

Comment: I gave you a bit of guidance, but please understand that your request is almost too broad. It is always better that you try things yourself first, and then show the code you are stuck with, instead of dropping some code and "now someone tell me how to test that".

Answer (score 1):

Many things to say here.

First of all, to answer your question. When a method doesn't return something, you can still can check whether some "other state" gets updated accordingly.

In your case, one meaningful point of observation could be that call

```
processLine(strLine);
```

In other words: you could see what that method is doing, and somehow verify that the other method was called as you would expect it.

Then: you actually wrote hard-to-test code. One reason for that is because this method starts its work on a **string** (that points to a file). Instead, you could pass a *reader* object to that method already. Then there wouldn't be a need to use PowerMock for example. You simply prepare a reader object that has known content, and then you can verify that actions follow that match that prepared content!

Beyond that, you should learn about try-with-resources, and you should also study more how to do IO. There is no point in closing all 3 streams. When you create a reader on some other stream, and you close the outer reader, that "base" stream gets closed automatically along the way.